# Kotlin inline function only have a return statement

Tags: kotlin, inline

I want to use inline function return outside function(skip print the "after"). So when I use

```
inline fun test() {
    return
}

fun test1() {
    println("before")
    test()
    println("after")
}
test1()
```

the output is

```
before  
after
```

When I use

```
inline fun test(callBack: () -> Unit) {
    callBack()
}

fun test1() {
    println("before")
    test {
        return
    }
    println("after")
}
test1()
```

the output is

```
before
```

So I want to know why the return statement in the first inline function is not working. Why does the first block of code not work?

Comment: Because the return in the inlined function returns from that function, not from the function where it is inlined.

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation:

> (return) by default returns from the nearest enclosing function or anonymous function. -- [returns-and-jumps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#returns-and-jumps)

> A return statement without a label always returns from the function declared with the fun keyword. -- [anonymous-functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions)

Actually I would revert the question: why does it work in the second example? And the answer is:

> In Kotlin, we can only use a normal, unqualified return to exit a named function or an anonymous function. This means that to exit a lambda, we have to use a label, and a bare return is forbidden inside a lambda, because a lambda cannot make the enclosing function return (...). But if the function the lambda is passed to is inlined, the return can be inlined as well, so it is allowed.
> -- [non local returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns)

Answer (score 1):

you can use kotlin **Crossinline**

Crossinline allows you to mark a lambda to forbid it from using non-local returns. If you remember, inline lambdas interprets return as non-local returns and return is not allowed on non-inlined lambdas

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    test1()
}


inline fun test(crossinline callBack: () -> Unit) {
    callBack()
}

fun test1() {
    println("before")
    test {
        return@test
    }
    println("after")
}
```

then the output will be has expectes